# Use a db hash table stored in memcache combined with a cron job to write to google app engine Datastore

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, memcached

I have a large pipeline in google app engine that stores intermediate work on the Datastore. This quickly fills my daily quota writes.

Instead I am thinking of having a hash table db object stored in memcache that the pipeline uses to store all intermediate results and have cron jobs that loop through all entries of the hash table db and write them in the Datastore. I will then be using the db object to read my data and only if something is not there i will be going to the Datastore.

Is there a library that does this? I am mostly interested in Java but python would work too. Any thoughts of things that might go wrong? I know things might be wiped out from the memcache but what should the expected performance gain be?

Comment: Main thought on what might go wrong is that memcache is not guaranteed and is not predictible - you have no control of data staying cached. You could probably get away with doing the work in memory, but would definitely need some fallback in order to recover from data loss in cache.

Comment: One obvious thing to check: Have you declared `index=False` on all of the properties that won't be using in searches? The properties that are indexed by default cause two index writes each. Those add up.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your case, I am under the opinion that [Objectify for GAE/J](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/) might be suitable for your need. It has a [Global Cache option](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#Caching) that back up your datastore entities in the memcache to reduce the number of reads to the datastore.

Keep in mind that the cache only works for put/get/delete operations, so a query would not be cached. Also, any put/delete operations would automatically update the cached entities.

EDIT: After some clarifications from the asker, it appears that what the asker need is a memcache for a write buffer instead of a read buffer, my suggestion is therefore no longer valid for his/her use case.

Comment: I understand that memcache is not predictable, but I am willing to take the chances. I am looking for something similar to the solution described as "Long-term persistence without waiting on the datastore" in http://bjk5.com/post/11766098283/app-engine-performance-hacks-youll-probably-never.

Comment: ah, so you want to buffer your put operations and only wrote them when the buffer is filled up? wouldn't this ends up using the same number of write quota? how would this reduce your write count?

Comment: No, because in the mean time, all updates will happen in the bugger(memcache) and I will only be charged for one write per entity.

My workflow involved downloading stuff from the facebook graph api, computing and updating values for entities, and then writing down the final data.

Comment: I see, I understand now, but after perusing the GAE Cupboard and the mailing list, I'm quite stumped on what library that might provide the functionality that you require. Guava's LoadingCache http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained have an in-memory cache that could be used to compute and recompute data from external source and cache the result, but I'm not sure if that might be useful for your project.